# Can I use xautolock or anything else to run a command when input is received after the timeout?

Tags: screen-lock, xautolock

I want to have my screen lock and backlight fade out after some delay, and then I want to have the backlight fade back in when I move the cursor or press a button. Having the screen fade out is easy enough with xautolock, but I can't figure out a way to have to fade back in when I do a keyboard or mouse action. Is it possible to achieve this with xautolock, or perhaps another tool?